# How to access parent scope variables inside ui.route - onEnter method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm using angularjs with angular ui route. In the parent state controller I have defined the scope variable `dataset`

How can I access the parent state scope within the child state `onEnter` method.

I tried this

```
.state('business.remove', {
     url: '/remove',
     onEnter: [...'$scope',...,
        function (...$scope,...) {
              ...
              $scope.$parent.dataset
```

But it gives an error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

Comment: you want to use parent state scope variable?

Comment: yes I want to use parent scope variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use of the variable, I think you might be able to do various things.

If you want to change it, you can use messaging from Lower to Upper scopes using `$scope.$emit('eventName', {someData})` in lower scope, and `$on('eventName', someFunction)` inside parent scope and do the changing in your function.

But if you're trying to read the variable, you can either define that variable with `$rootScope` in parent and use it elsewhere, or define it inside a service then call the service and manipulate your data whenever needed...

In addition to these, you can go one step further with the first way(messaging), and send another message from parent scope to the child, using `$broadcast` and send that variable inside it to be read with `$on` inside the child scope... bud I don't know if it's a very optimized solution!

Hope that's helpful

Comment: Thank you. I try to avoid using rootscope. Currently working it out as you told with events. I want to alter the object in the parent scope. So it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In UI-Router, resolves should be used to load your applications primary data.  Resolves can propagate down to child states, and are useful to manage lifecycle;  They are loaded when a state is entered and go away when the state is exited.  You can create a resolve on your parent state and inject it into the parent or child views (controller), and/or the onEnter/onExit hooks.

```
.state('business', {
 url: '/remove',
 resolve: { 
     dataset: function(someService) { 
        someService.fetchDataset();
     }
 },
 controller: function(dataset, $scope) {
    // do something with dataset
 }

.state('business.remove', {
 url: '/remove',
 onEnter: function (dataset) {
     // do something else with dataset
```

Comment: Do you have a working example? I tried it but it fails with `Unknown provider` at `onEnter`.

Comment: For future reference, I found one here: http://plnkr.co/edit/a7slXklU5BQc61BVbbk1?p=preview